# how to pass Database name when it has a slash in name?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have to connect to a database using JDBC and database name is like-
     testserver\REPL_DISTRIBUTOR

I have tried like -
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://testserver\REPL_DISTRIBUTOR:1433/test;useCursors=true;bufferMaxMemory=10240;lobBuffer=5242880;socketTimeout=300;appName=symds
but getting error.

```
connection refused
```

Comment: try using two backslashes instead of one:  jdbc:mysql://testserver\\REPL_DISTRIBUTOR:14.....

Comment: Thanks. I tried that already before posting. additional info, I am using this path thru symmetricDS replication tool.

Comment: Is this SQL Server or MySQL? Your tag says SQL Server and connection string is mysql

Comment: @Alex the connection string is a combination of parts of a MySQL and an SQL Server connection string

Comment: Mark ,Alex...Sorry for that. re-edited the string for connection.i am trying to connect couple of servers fe mysql and others sql server. Connection successful with mysql but getting error with sql server.